# Update jquery ui dialog from another jquery ui dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog and from this one, i open another dialog, where user insert some data. How can I update this user data from the second dialog to the first one, without closing them?

Is this possible? Are some examples in the web?

Thanks in advance

---

ok so this is my script, which opens the second dialog. I open this dialog with a link, which calls a function in my mvc controller, and this returns the partial view with the datas...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#dialog2").dialog({
                  bgiframe: false,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 200,
                  resizable: false,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                  OK: function () {
                       $("#dialog2 > form").submit();
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                 },
                  Abbrechen: function () {
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                   }
                   }
                  });
                $('#changePW').click(function () {
            $('#dialog1').dialog('open')    
             });
           });
      </script>
```

@Roysvork: then I have to but this in the buttons OK function?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Far easier if you show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dialog is simply an html element underneath, you can still access said element using jQuery in the usual fashion:

```
var dialog1 = $("#dialog1");
var dialog2 = $("#dialog2");

dialog1.dialog("show");
dialog2.dialog("show");
```

So in your event handler for dialog 1 you can just do :

```
var value = dialog2.find("#inputbox").val();
dialog2.find("#textbox").val(value) ;
```

etc...

Comment: I cannot comment on the above as I'm still building up points, but yes is the answer. It is also better to keep your jquery objects in variables and reuse them as each time you use a selector, it searches the whole page which can get slow.